Fast merge of flat collection with same key to a dictionary of values
I get objects which have 2 main properties - an outer key (int) and a dictionary that is keyed by a string with list of values.
Internal keys (A/B in the example) are supposed to be unique for each outer key (1).
This needs to be optimised for .net 8 with the following considerations - the code is run a few times a second and there are about 20 outer keys and 3-5 internal keys and value lists are about 100 elements each
v1 = new { Key = 1, D = new Dictionary<string, List<double>> { new {"A", new { 10, 11 } } } };
v1 = new { Key = 1, D = new Dictionary<string, List<double>> { new {"B", new { 20, 22 } } } };

expected result : Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, List<double>> ->
{ 1, { { "A", {10,11} }, { "B", {20,22} } }}


With these numbers it seems that a straight-forward approach would work fine.

What did you mean by "to be optimised for .net 8"? I can't think of any new features in .net 8 that involve such optimization.

Indeed. I'd recommend benchmarking the simplest approach first, and see whether it meets your requirements, rather than assuming you need a particularly heavily-optimised approach to start with. (You might want to specify StringComparer.Ordinal though for the dictionaries - IIRC that on its own can improve performance quite significantly, as well as avoiding some hard-to-diagnose issues.)

Here is a solution with LINQ, assuming objs contains an IEnumerable<T> containing those objects with outer keys.
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<String, List<double>>> result = objs
    .GroupBy(
        x => x.Key, x => x.D
    )
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key, 
        g => g.SelectMany(x => x).ToDictionary()
    );

First group by the outer key and we want groups of D. Then, use each group's key as the key of the resulting dictionary. The values of the resulting dictionary will be the dictionaries in that group all merged. The merging is done by .SelectMany(x => x), which creates a flat sequence of all the key value pairs. Finally ToDictionary converts this flat sequence of key value pairs to a dictionary.

As question mentions performance, might consider avoiding Linq, because it is slower than more elaborative implementation with loops. In my benchmarks Linq was 2.4 times slower than the same implementation with loops. Code below ran 0.254 second in average for Linq version and 0.106 second for loop version, on .NET 8.
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
...
public class Benchmarks
{
    private record Input(
        int Key,
        Dictionary<string, List<double>> D);
    
    static Dictionary<string, List<double>> A = new Dictionary<string, List<double>> { 
            {"A", new List<double>{ 10, 11 } }
    };
    
    static Dictionary<string, List<double>> B = new Dictionary<string, List<double>> { 
            {"B", new List<double>{ 20, 22 } }
    };
    
    private static IEnumerable<Input> Gen2() {
        for(int i = 0; i< 100_000; i++) {
            yield return new Input(Key: i, D: A );
            yield return new Input(Key: i, D: B );
        }
    }

    private static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, List<double>>> LinqImplementation(IEnumerable<Input> objs) 
    {
        return objs
            .GroupBy(
                ...
            )
            .ToDictionary(
                ...
            );
    }

    private static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, List<double>>> LoopImplementation(IEnumerable<Input> objs) 
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, List<double>>>();
        foreach(var obj in objs) {
            if (!result.TryGetValue(obj.Key, out Dictionary<string, List<double>> val))
            {
                val = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();
                result.Add(obj.Key, val);
            }
            
            foreach(var kvp in obj.D) {
                val.TryAdd(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    [Benchmark]
    public static void LinqImplementationBenchmark()
    {
        LinqImplementation(Gen2());
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public static void LoopImplementationBenchmark()
    {
        LoopImplementation(Gen2());
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    BenchmarkRunner.Run<Benchmarks>();
}


yeah i did the exact same thing as in your Loop version.. ill wait a day and see if anyone can better that
